# How to read an lp file with CPLEX?

Tags: file, linear-programming, cplex

I am new to using CPLEX. I have an lp file and should solve it. How do I implement it in CPLEX? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid having to do any programming at all, just use the CPLEX commandline tool. This is **cplex.exe** on windows, e.g. in

C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio129\cplex\bin\x64_win64.

You will find something similar on other systems like Linux or MacOS. This lets you read, solve and write out your solution using the commands 'read', 'opt' and 'write' like this:

```
C:\Users\Tim>cplex

Welcome to IBM(R) ILOG(R) CPLEX(R) Interactive Optimizer 12.9.0.0
...

CPLEX> read "location.lp"
Problem location.lp' read.
Read time = 0.05 sec. (0.00 ticks)
CPLEX> opt
Tried aggregator 1 time.

...

MIP - Integer optimal solution:  Objective =  4.9900000000e+02
Solution time =    0.19 sec.  Iterations = 124  Nodes = 0
Deterministic time = 7.91 ticks  (42.08 ticks/sec)

CPLEX> write location.sol
Incumbent solution written to file 'location.sol'.
CPLEX> quit
```

The cplex commandline tool is **very** useful tool when you get to know it.

Comment: Yes exactly, thanks! I was looking forward in using something like this that allows me no use of coding, since I have a .lp file, in the correct format, and just need for CPLEX to read it and solve it. Anyhow I have some problem using it, it tells me it can't find any such .lp file I tell him to read, even though this file is in the same directory of the Interactive Optimizer. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks very much.

Comment: Should be able read it - check for things like having a space in the filename etc. Also you can give a full pathname.

Answer (score 1):

if I use the [zoo example](https://medium.com/@alexfleischer_84755/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-66940178db6) with bus.lp

```
\ENCODING=ISO-8859-1
\Problem name: broken

Minimize
 obj: 500 nbBus40 + 400 nbBus30
Subject To
 ctAllKidsNeedToGo: 40 nbBus40 + 30 nbBus30 >= 300

Bounds
      nbBus40 >= 0
      nbBus30 >= 0
Generals
 nbBus40  nbBus30 
End
```

then in OPL

```
main
{
  cplex.importModel("bus.lp");
  cplex.solve();
  writeln(cplex.getObjValue());
}
```

gives

3800